# Placing a div over a jQuery image slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tools, jquery-scrollable

I'm trying to place a div element over the a [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html) image gallery. I've got everything placed in the right way, however the div doesn't appear on top of the jQuery object even if I set z-index: 2. Here's my code:

```
div#wrapperContainer{
display: table;
overflow: hidden;
margin: -5px auto;
}

//this is the div i'm trying to put on top of the jQuery Tool
div#wrapper {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
z-index: 2;
width: 1024px;
height: 192px;
background-color: #525252;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 50px #000; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 50px #000; 
        box-shadow: 0px -10px 50px #000;
}

//this is the CSS for the jQuery Tool

.scrollable {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 940px;
height: 528px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
}

.items {
width: 20000em;
clear: both;
position: absolute;
}

.items  div{
float: left;
width: 940px;
height: 528px;
}
```

Comment: do you want this done with pure css or are you ok using jQuery?

Comment: which do you think might work better?

Answer (score 3):

Can you position the wrapper div absolutely?
If so, that should take care of it, along with a proper z-index.

See the positioning example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Crk3r/).

Comment: I'd go with this one too. The scrollable is already relative, make the new one absolute and put a high z-index.

Comment: can I keep the div center if I position it absolutely?

Comment: You can't center it the regular way (like you do with relatively positioned elements), but you can position it using margin-top and margin-left parameters.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it messes up my design if the window gets resized. I've got to find another solution or rethink the design.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`jQuery.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: I don't think this might help, maybe I haven't described the problem correctly: I need to show both the jQuery Tool and the div, which I want to be laying on top of the jQuery Tool, but hiding it only partially.